# How can I continue merging after a double-modify?

Tags: git, conflict, rebase

I'm using `git rebase -i` to rewrite history — in this case, make a small alteration to an earlier commit's change set.  In other words,

```
A---B---C master

      --->

A---B'--C master
```

I know `C` is implicitly changing, too, but you get the idea.  Here's my progress so far:

1. `git rebase -i HEAD~2`
2. Change `B` from `keep` to `edit`.
3. Edit the file.
4. `git commit -a --amend`
5. `git rebase --continue`
6. "Could not apply [C]..."

I've resolved the conflicted lines in `C`, but am unsure how to mark it as resolved so that the rebase can continue.  `git commit --amend` attempts to amend `B`, while `git rebase --continue` complains that the working tree is dirty.  (And, sure enough, `git status` shows the file as "both modified".)

What do I need to do to get this rebase back on track?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you run into the conflicts, you should see a message something like this:

```
error: could not apply 45cb26a... <commit message subject>
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' and run 'git rebase --continue'
```

And that's exactly what you need to do:

```
# resolve the conflicts somehow
git add <conflicted-file>
git rebase --continue
```

Don't try to use `commit --amend`. `HEAD` (the current commit) still refers to the one just before, since the conflicts have prevented this commit from being made, so as you saw, that just amends the already-applied commit. `rebase --continue` will proceed to make the new commit containing the resolved conflicts.

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thanks for the help, I missed that line in the output.  ;-)

Comment: @Ben: That's a pretty easy one to miss, since as long as you have some idea what you're doing, you immediately go resolve the conflicts, and forget anything was up there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing it explicitly, i.e.:  `git add B'`, then committing it with `--amend`, then doing `git rebase --continue`?

Comment: Won't that create a new commit?  I'm simply trying to get `C` to apply.

Comment: Sorry I meant adding B' explicitly, then doing commit --amend.

Comment: I already amended `B` and tried to continue.  Right now, my repo is in a state where `B'` is the most recent commit in the log, but the changes from `C` have been applied (including my additional changes to resolve the conflict).

Comment: I see that you are doing git commit -a --amend. Did the amend create new untracked files? Otherwise it should have been fine when you gave git rebase --continue

Comment: @manojlds — I aborted the `commit --amend` when I saw that it wanted to further modify `B'` (which I assume would have squashed the two commits).

Comment: You don't want to amend here, and `B'` is a commit, not a path; `git add B'` doesn't make sense.